# How to change gcc environment variables on windows?

Tags: mingw

I read a lot about this and still haven't found an answer to my question:
How to change the CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH variables under windows(mingw)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` command in mingw command prompt. (the same window you invoke GCC from)
Note that the change will only be effective in the same command prompt you've used the set command in. It won't be preserved for further mingw invocations.

To make those arrangements permanent, you can create a script file which sets those variables - or even set them system-wide.